# What is that famous diner from When Harry Met Sally?

Tags: film-location, when-harry-met-sally

[image: When Harry Met Sally diner]

I've seen movies that take it to another level by [doing scenes in real restaurants](https://vimeo.com/183364902).

But I was wondering where this scene took place in. It doesn't look like a movie set. So I'm assuming it happened in a real diner. What is the name of this place. And where is it located?

Answer (score 12):

Katz's Delicatessen in New York's Lower East Side!

---

[People Magazine](http://www.people.com/article/when-harry-meet-sally-deli-scene-ill-have-what-shes-having) did an article on it, as well as the NY Times.

> It's curious how the single best line in Nora Ephron's script for When
>   Harry Met Sally..., released July 14, 1989, is spoken by neither Harry
>   nor Sally. Instead, it's an unnamed character who reacts to Sally's
>   fake orgasm in Katz's Deli with, "I'll have what she's having."

I've also eaten there numerous times, so I speak from personal knowledge.  *(Just about any New Yorker can validate this.)*

Comment: I've allowed myself to copy a piece from the article you linked into your answer. Btw. I've recently read (in an article about pastrami in a culinary magazine) that the place doesn't exist anymore, is it true?

Comment: Still at the corner of Houston and Ludlow, as far as I know.  [Katz's Website](http://www.katzsdelicatessen.com/)

Comment: The unnamed character is played by Estelle Reiner, Rob Reiner's mother.

Comment: [There is a sign](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Harry_und_Sally_bei_Katz'_Deli.JPG) hanging from the ceiling that marks the table where that scene was filmed. When I used to go there as a teenager in the 1980s it was just a place to get an excellent pastrami on rye. Now, it's a quite a tourist destination.